# Python plotting meteorological field. I have data at 1000hPa, but I don't know why when I output the data, it is Nan

Tags: python

I'm facing an issue with my code where the output is returning 'NAN' (Not a Number). The interesting part is that the data appears to be valid at 1000hPa. However, if I change the level to other values, such as 850hPa, I can see the data.

**Here is my code:**

```
import numpy as np
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import xarray as xr
import xarray as xr
def load_data(time_array, var_name, ds):
    data = sum(ds[var_name].loc[time,1000, 25:36, 115:128] for time in time_array) / len(time_array)
    return data

time_array = [
'2010-07-16T03',
'2011-06-09T04',
'2011-06-09T20',
'2011-08-18T10',
'2014-07-12T06',
'2016-06-19T10',
'2016-06-20T19',
'2016-06-21T08',
'2017-04-06T08',
'2017-06-29T03',
'2017-06-30T02',
'2017-08-17T08',
'2017-08-18T03',
'2017-08-19T03',
'2017-09-24T18']

ds1 = xr.open_dataset('D:/filter_nc/minor3hbig.nc')
T1 = load_data(time_array, 't', ds1)
print(T1)
```

**Output**

```
<xarray.DataArray 't' (lat: 45, lon: 53)>
    array([[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
           [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
           [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
           ...,
           [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
           [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
           [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan]], dtype=float32)
    Coordinates:
        level    int32 1000
       * lon      (lon) float32 115.0 115.2 115.5 115.8 ... 127.2 127.5 127.8 128.0
       * lat      (lat) float32 25.0 25.25 25.5 25.75 26.0 ... 35.25 35.5 35.75 36.0
         time     datetime64[ns] 2017-09-24T18:00:00
```

Do you happen to know how I can fix this issue and why this is happening? Your insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Many things look wrong in your code and the way you select the data. I would suggest you to have a look to the xarray tutorial to learn more about how to select the data you want.
This will help you write a more understandable code for yourself and others.

https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html